# MySQL : Left join with group by records

Tags: mysql, left-join, limit

I have 2 tables

Job

```
id | job_num | comp_date
-----------------------------
 1 | J01     | NULL
 2 | J02     | NULL
 3 | J03     | NULL
 4 | J04     | NULL
 5 | J05     | NULL
```

apt

```
id | job_id | status | apt_date   | user_id
-----------------------------------------
1  | 1      | 1      | 2018-08-09 | 1
2  | 1      | 1      | 2018-08-09 | 2
3  | 2      | 2      | 2018-08-09 | 1
```

And i'm trying to get data from 2 tables with left join where limit

### Query

```
SELECT j.* , a.* FROM `job` j 
LEFT JOIN apt a 
ON j.id = a.job_id AND a.status = 1
Group by a.date
```

### Result

```
id | job_num | comp_date| id | job_id | status | apt_date
---------------------------------------------------------
 2 | J02     | NULL     |NULL|NULL    | NULL   | NULL
 1 | J01     | NULL     | 1  |1       | 1      | 2018-06-05
```

I need all data from Job table and from 1 record from apt table where status 1

### Expected Output

```
id | job_num | comp_date| id | job_id | status | apt_date
---------------------------------------------------------
 1 | J01     | NULL     | 1  |1       | 1      | 2018-06-05
 2 | J02     | NULL     |NULL|NULL    | NULL   | NULL
 3 | J03     | NULL     |NULL|NULL    | NULL   | NULL
 4 | J04     | NULL     |NULL|NULL    | NULL   | NULL
 5 | J05     | NULL     |NULL|NULL    | NULL   | NULL
```

How to group by record ?

Comment: You could join to a subquery on the apt table, with a limit in that sub-query.

Comment: Well , I want apt table data with group by if not . On apt status if status = 1 then apt_date always same for all status 1 for that job

Comment: Limit based on what order? What if there are more than one date for that `apt`, `job_id`, and `status`. Which one do you want? Which user_id?

Comment: Thats hwy i want to group it by apt_dae

Comment: If you group apt by date and there are multiple dates for a `job_id` with `status` of 1 then you will get multiple records back for each `job.id`. Is that what you want? Can you share more sample data that shows this scenario and what your desired results are for that? It's not very clear what you are trying to do with this very limited sample.

Comment: @JNevill : I have updated post

Comment: Use proper `GROUP BY`!!!

Comment: @Eric : Already did it but result it not as expected one.

Comment: @Aanshi If you say you use a proper `GROUP BY`, why don't I see `j.id, j.job_num,a.id, a.job_id, a.status, a.user_id` in your GROUP BY????

Comment: @Aanshi Your query doesn't make sense.  That's why you don't get the correct result.

Answer (score -2):

Finally I found it.

```
SELECT j.* , a.* FROM `job` j 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `apt` WHERE `date` IS NOT NULL AND status =1 GROUP by `date`) as a 
ON j.id = a.job_id
```